# React JS Nested elements both use same onClick event and child event is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a todos list that I am working on. I want to be able to mark the task complete by clicking the checkbox or anywhere in the div of that todo. However, I get a warning when I only have the onClick event on the parent component

Here is the component code that works but gives me a warning:

```js
render(){
    const {todo, handleClick} = this.props;
    const className = this.getClassName(todo.complete)
    return (
      <div
      className={className}
      onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="todo-checkbox"
          checked={todo.complete}
        />
        <span
          className='todo-text'>
          {todo.text}
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and here is the warning:

> index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

To fix this I used the suggested e.stopPropagation(); and added an onChange event to the child element. However, now only the parent div is working, so I can change successfully mark a todo anywhere in the div except for the checkbox. I think this is because they share the same method that it's not separating them as two different events.

```js
  stopBubbling = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }

  handleChange = (e, key) => {
    this.stopBubbling(e)
    this.setCompletebyId(e, key)
  }

  setCompletebyId = (e, key) => {
    const { todos } = this.state;
    const index = key - 1;
    const complete = todos[index].complete;
    todos[index].complete = !complete;
    this.setState({
      todos
    })
  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a `<label>` instead of a `<div>`? Labels are kind of built for what you're trying to accomplish. Just give the label element an `htmlFor` attribute that matches the checkbox's `id` attribute :)

Comment: Thank you! I just did this and changing the `<div>` to `<label>` solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `onClick` in your first example on the `input` itself and not the `div`?

From React's perspective, it assumes the input is "uncontrolled" and the user cannot interact with it. So the warning is providing options if that is the case. But in this scenario, you want it to be [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). It was working because the click event on the `input` checkbox would bubble up to the `div` and still invoke the click handler.

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { todo, handleClick } = this.props;

    return (
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className="todo-checkbox"
          onClick={handleClick}
          checked={todo.complete}
        />
        {todo.text}
      </label>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todo: { complete: false, text: "TODO" }
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ todo: { ...this.state.todo, complete: !this.state.todo.complete } });
  };

  render() {
    const { todo } = this.state;

    return <Checkbox todo={todo} handleClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this was a great reference! Changing the `<div>` to `<label>` solved the issue I was having and I'm not getting a warning anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting 
onChange = {handleClick}
inside the input tag might help as a checkbox expects an onChange function.